# ReadLine - execute twice?

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

I need to be able to read each line of the file for multiple arguments, hence the for loop. After the first one, it does not seem to be reading them anymore, seems to skip the try statement. Any ideas? I'm sure Its something silly I am missing but have been playing about with it and unfortunately time is not on my side.

```
for (int j = 0; j < ags.length; j++){

 try{
String nameFromFile = null;
BufferedReader InputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while ((nameFromFile = InputReader.readLine()) != null) {

    // Do stuff

} catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions you are getting?

Comment: Print `ags.length` before the loop.

Comment: what is the length of ags?

Comment: Are you supposed to be typing in the lines or getting filenames from  from `ags` ?

Comment: @VinayakPingale. It is two, the length is correct and on each time it is getting the correct values. However when I try to match it to the input stream the second time, nothing is appearing. No Exceptions

Comment: @PeterLawrey my command is `Program Name1 Name1 < names.txt` and I am matching the names if they appear in the text file

Comment: I suspect "new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));"... Did you really mean to use System.in or using the ags[j] here???

Comment: Try using catch(Throwable thr) instead of IOException to capture any run time exceptions which might not have been thought of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have two sources you want to compare `System.in` and `args`  I suggest you read these individually and then compare them.

```
Set<String> fromInt = new HashSet<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;)
        fromIn.add(normalise(line));
}
// compare argsList with fromIn.
```

e.g.

```
for(String arg: args) {
    if (fromIn.contains(normalise(arg))) {
       // something
    } else {
       // something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the list be split to look at each match individually?

Comment: @NatalieCarr yes, by most likely you don't need to.  How do you want to compare them? e.g. do you want the union, the words in one but not the other.

Comment: Certain things are changed before I can make a match. For instance some letters have equivalence so I look at both strings and normalize them and check if they match, then move to the next name.

Comment: @NatalieCarr added an example of what you could do.

Comment: After several attempts, I dont think this will work for me. But Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to be able to read each line of the file

What file? You're reading from `System.in:`

```
BufferedReader InputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Your code will block at this line until you enter something at the console.

Comment: I am reading the file in like so: `Program Name1 Name1 < names.txt`

Comment: Then you should have said so in your question instead of wasting my time. You also need to confide in us why you're reading the same file `ags.length` times.

Comment: I think thats my problem, I should only be reading it once and using the data `ags.length` times. Trying to solve this now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not read a file, bu the System.in stream.

Every stream has an internal pointer, so the stream nows, which line was read at last.

If the System stream was read once, the pointer is pointing to the end of the stream.
As long as the stream is not reset, the read command will not return anything.

try

[InputStream.reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29)

or even better, only read the Stream once and cache the result! This is faster and safe, because the Stream input can change during iteration.

Comment: While reset() works on files, it wouldn't expect it to work on console input. ;)

Comment: of course, it depends on the stream, but this is described in the javadoc too. Anyways the stream should be read once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never exit from while loop.

```
while ((nameFromFile = InputReader.readLine()) != null)
```

In above loop it will print only one time and at the end of the file it will not be out of the while loop . That's why you are getting only one time output. Since it is not exited from while loop it does not go back into for loop. readLine() return the string and it is terminated by "\n" or "\r\n". Change as below and you will be able to read as ags.length

```
while ((nameFromFile = InputReader.readLine())=="\n")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, Unfortunately this did not work, no errors just not getting any values, even for the first loop.

Comment: Having the same output with both changes.